# How to check response of requests GET request exact size?

Tags: python, python-requests, size

If I'm sending a GET request using `requests` module:

```
response = requests.get('https://example.com')
```

And then I want to check what's the size of the response content so I'm using this code:

```
len(response.content)
```

And the result of this `len` is `2671` for example.
So how much is it? 2671 bytes or a different measure unit?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get the content of a response object then you get the HTML code of that website in the format of `bytes`. Now knowing that each word(or char. I was not using char as there is nothing like char in python. It is in languages like C) is one byte. It is similar to string in python. So if you try to `len(response.content)` you get the length of the HTML code in bytes.

Comment: Each word is **not** one byte.

Comment: but `len(b'a')` gives output of 1. when means length of this is 1

Comment: Try `len(b'word')` which is 4 with "word" being a word but `4 != 1`.

Comment: by `each word` I mean a char and `word` is not a char

Comment: But then "char" is not a real concept in a byte string =) just a little nitpicking: a char is what any number of bytes in the `bytes` object might represent depending on the encoding. Take `b'T\xc3\xbcr'` which has length 4, but (given utf-8 encoding) represents only 3 chars.

Comment: The output of `b'T\xc3\xbcr'` is totally correct as you have used \x characters and in python `\x` characters are used as a single byte so here `T` `\xc3` `\xbc` `r` are of 4 bytes. But when we talk about ASCII alphabets then there is no difference in the length of a string or byte.

Comment: My point entirely. It's 4 bytes, but 3 chars (or characters since we are not talking about python data type, but a linguistic concept). Nevermind :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find this out by a simple script as:

```
import requests, sys

url="https://www.google.com/"
res = requests.get(url)
x = res.content
typeX = type(x)
print(typeX)
print(sys.getsizeof(typeX)*len(x))
```

Here the `type(response)` is `bytes` and to get the size of object `bytes` in bytes, we can we use the `getsizeof` functionality from `sys` module.

The above script will output the size of the response in bytes.

Comment: I am fairly certain the OP is not interested in the memory usage of the response content Python object .

Comment: IIUC, OP is interested in knowing what is the object type for the returned length which is of type `bytes` object in Python and to get the size of the response in `bytes (8 bits)`, I used the `getsizeof` method. I tried to answer for what I interpreted from the question :)